# submitting form through modal footer button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

In my system i display form in bootstrap modal using Ajax rendering. form default submit button work correctly. but i need to submit form through modal footer button that added by me.

**index page**

```
<div class="term-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Term', ['create'], ['class' => 'create btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

     <?php 
        Modal::begin([
            'header'=>'<h4></h4>',
            'id'=> 'modal',
            'size'=>'modal-md',
            'footer' => '<div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button> 
                         </div>

                         <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>'
            ]);

        echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";

        Modal::end();
    ?>



    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'name',
            'description:ntext',
            'date',
            'user_id',
            // 'brach_id',
            // 'start_date',
            // 'end_date',
            // 'academic_year_id',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

**form view**

```
<div class="term-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(TermType::find()->all(),'name','name'),['prompt' => '']); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'brach_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Branch::find()->all(),'id','name'),['prompt' => '']); ?>
    <label>start date</label>
    <?= DatePicker::widget([ 'model' => $model, 'attribute' => 'start_date','class'=>'form-control input-sm', 'size' => 'sm', 'template' => '{addon}{input}', 'clientOptions' => [ 'autoclose' => true, 'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd','label'=>'start date' ] ]);?>

    <br/>
    <label>end date</label>
    <?= DatePicker::widget([ 'model' => $model, 'attribute' => 'end_date', 'class'=>'form-control input-sm', 'size' => 'sm', 'template' => '{addon}{input}', 'clientOptions' => [ 'autoclose' => true, 'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd', ] ]);?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'academic_year_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(BranchHasAcademicYear::find()->all(),'id','academic_year_name'),['prompt' => '']) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and **j query function** is

```
$('body').on('click','.create',function()
    {

       var href = $(this).attr('href');


       $('#modal').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContent').load(href);
       return false;

    });
```

Comment: Did you encounter a problem with the footer button? What have you tried (post code). What is the question?

Comment: problem is button is appear in the modal window but when i click it validation or submit process is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Bind the footer button click with JS Onclick Handler and then use AJAX to submit your form. I have never used Modal so I cannot give a code snippet.

Easiest option IMHO is using Jui Dialogs. Here is sample code with JUI doing the same as modal (just to give you idea)

```
Dialog::begin([
    'clientOptions' => [
        'modal' => true,
        'buttons'=>[
            'Submit'=> new JsExpression("
                function()
                {
                    //select form by ID
                    //submit with AJAX
                }
            ")
        ]
    ],
]);

echo 'Dialog contents here...';

Dialog::end();
```